# Bootstrap Label For Responsiveness

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I searched around, and I could have missed something, but I'm trying to get my labels, on an input form, to dynamically change margin for alignment using Bootstrap 4.5.  My issue is that I have a form with four  input blocks, and a button, across, in columns (in a row), that are:

```
col-md-3 col-sm-12
col-md-3 col-sm-12
col-md-2 col-sm-12
col-md-2 col-sm-12
col-md-2 col-sm-12
```

So that if it's a medium screen size or bigger, each column takes up the appropriate amount, or if it's small, they show up in rows, one after the other.  My problem is that I have a "label for" control above each input, and as the size shrinks between medium and small, the label moves to two lines and then throws off all the alignment until it is in the small view.

Here is a sample HTML of one of the rows:

```
<div class="row" id="rowSubTask0">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12"><label for="STName0">Sub Task Name:</label><input class="form-control" type="text" id="STName0" placeholder="Name" name="STName0"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12"><label for="STDesc0">Sub Task Description:</label><input class="form-control" type="text" id="STDesc0" placeholder="Description" name="STDesc0"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12"><label for="STDefaultHours0">Expected Hours:</label><input class="form-control" type="number" id="STDefaultHours0" placeholder="Default Hours" name="STDefaultHours0"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12"><label for="STDefaultPrice0">Expected Price (Optional):</label><input class="form-control" type="number" step="0.01" id="STDefaultPrice0" placeholder="Default Price" name="STDefaultPrice0"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12  align-self-end"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="btnRemoveSub0" role="button" onclick="RemoveSubTask('rowSubTask0', 'Pipeline');"><i class="mdi mdi-minus-circle text-danger"></i> Delete</a></div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure exactly how to fix this?

See images for a better explanation:
Shows How it looks at medium, large, xl, etc, which is how I want it to look:
[image: Desired behavior at medium or larger]

Shows how the label on the right word wraps and causes spacing on the others to look funny somewhere between medium and small:
[image: Undesired label behavior once window size shrinks a bit]

Shows what it looks like, as desired, in the small view:
[image: View on the small screen]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible for you to put all the label on a seperate div on top (like a header) on desktop and hide it on small? And do the reverse for label with the input fields. You will have your label twice in the DOM but your thing look like a table on desktop that why i ask you that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have try to do something quick for you tell me if it's fits what you want to achieve.

Basically i put labels twice and hide label that we don't want.

```css
.row {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row d-none d-md-flex align-items-center bg-primary">
  <div class="col-3">Sub Task Name:</div>
  <div class="col-3">Sub Task Description:</div>
  <div class="col-2">Expected Hours:</div>
  <div class="col-2">Expected Price (Optional) this is to long:</div>
  <div class="col-2"></div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="rowSubTask0">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12"><label class="d-block d-md-none" for="STName0">Sub Task Name:</label><input class="form-control" type="text" id="STName0" placeholder="Name" name="STName0"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12"><label class="d-block d-md-none" for="STDesc0">Sub Task Description:</label><input class="form-control" type="text" id="STDesc0" placeholder="Description" name="STDesc0"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12"><label class="d-block d-md-none" for="STDefaultHours0">Expected Hours:</label><input class="form-control" type="number" id="STDefaultHours0" placeholder="Default Hours" name="STDefaultHours0"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12"><label class="d-block d-md-none" for="STDefaultPrice0">Expected Price (Optional):</label><input class="form-control" type="number" step="0.01" id="STDefaultPrice0" placeholder="Default Price" name="STDefaultPrice0"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12  align-self-end"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="btnRemoveSub0" role="button" onclick="RemoveSubTask('rowSubTask0', 'Pipeline');"><i class="mdi mdi-minus-circle text-danger"></i> Delete</a></div>

</div>
<div class="row" id="rowSubTask0">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12"><label class="d-block d-md-none" for="STName0">Sub Task Name:</label><input class="form-control" type="text" id="STName0" placeholder="Name" name="STName0"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12"><label class="d-block d-md-none" for="STDesc0">Sub Task Description:</label><input class="form-control" type="text" id="STDesc0" placeholder="Description" name="STDesc0"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12"><label class="d-block d-md-none" for="STDefaultHours0">Expected Hours:</label><input class="form-control" type="number" id="STDefaultHours0" placeholder="Default Hours" name="STDefaultHours0"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12"><label class="d-block d-md-none" for="STDefaultPrice0">Expected Price (Optional):</label><input class="form-control" type="number" step="0.01" id="STDefaultPrice0" placeholder="Default Price" name="STDefaultPrice0"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12  align-self-end"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="btnRemoveSub0" role="button" onclick="RemoveSubTask('rowSubTask0', 'Pipeline');"><i class="mdi mdi-minus-circle text-danger"></i> Delete</a></div>

</div>
<div class="row" id="rowSubTask0">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12"><label class="d-block d-md-none" for="STName0">Sub Task Name:</label><input class="form-control" type="text" id="STName0" placeholder="Name" name="STName0"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12"><label class="d-block d-md-none" for="STDesc0">Sub Task Description:</label><input class="form-control" type="text" id="STDesc0" placeholder="Description" name="STDesc0"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12"><label class="d-block d-md-none" for="STDefaultHours0">Expected Hours:</label><input class="form-control" type="number" id="STDefaultHours0" placeholder="Default Hours" name="STDefaultHours0"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12"><label class="d-block d-md-none" for="STDefaultPrice0">Expected Price (Optional):</label><input class="form-control" type="number" step="0.01" id="STDefaultPrice0" placeholder="Default Price" name="STDefaultPrice0"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12  align-self-end"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="btnRemoveSub0" role="button" onclick="RemoveSubTask('rowSubTask0', 'Pipeline');"><i class="mdi mdi-minus-circle text-danger"></i> Delete</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to get the desired behavior I was looking for.  It's a lot more HTML than I was expecting, especially since I dynamically create this in JS and PHP in places.  Appreciate the help.

Answer (score -1):

Its easy to fix this issue, you have to specify xl-12 for extra-large screens in div to ensure that its occupying 12 columns. Furthermore to enable the columns should render, put that div in a row container. Check out https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp for further information.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.  the div is in a row, I edited my post so you can see the full row, with the columns.  Your suggestion is to add xl-12 to each of the columns? I thought by it being md-12 that means any screen size greater than medium it will take up 12 columns?  Which will include the xl?  The issue is somewhere between medium and small, when the label cannot fit on one line, it word wraps and causes all the labels to mis-align.